# Python Graph API Client Exception - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am following the guide on: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python to build a Python package that can pull all my devices from Azure AD (Entra). I have confirmed good working API credentials and that they have the right permissions:

My code is below

```
async def get_AADdevices():
    MScredential = ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id=os.environ['MSGraphTenantID'],
        client_id=os.environ['MSGraphClientID'],
        client_secret=os.environ['MSGraphClientSecret']
    )
    scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    client = GraphServiceClient(credentials=MScredential, scopes=scopes)
    devices = await client.devices.get()
```

I am getting the following error when it calls the `await client.devices.get()`:

```
Executed 'Functions.MachineReconciliation' (Failed, Id=d6a7b205-25fc-4dfa-ad22-3621ed0b4144, Duration=9ms)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.MachineReconciliation. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 479, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 752, in _run_sync_func
    return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper
    result = function(**args)
  File "C:\Users\<path>\function_app.py", line 17, in MachineReconciliation
    asyncio.run(get_AADdevices())
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\<path>\function_app.py", line 40, in get_AADdevices
    devices = await client.devices.get()
  File "C:\Users\<path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\msgraph\generated\devices\devices_request_builder.py", line 70, in get
    return await self.request_adapter.send_async(request_info, DeviceCollectionResponse, error_mapping)
  File "C:\Users\<path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\kiota_http\httpx_request_adapter.py", line 162, in send_async
    parent_span = self.start_tracing_span(request_info, "send_async")
  File "C:\Users\<path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\kiota_http\httpx_request_adapter.py", line 131, in start_tracing_span
    uri_template = ParametersNameDecodingHandler.decode_uri_encoded_string(
  File "C:\Users\<path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\kiota_http\middleware\parameters_name_decoding_handler.py", line 92, in decode_uri_encoded_string
    name, value = name_value.split('=')
```

Any ideas?

I am expecting it to return a list of devices

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug on newer versions. I was having the same problem and rolling back to version a14 did the trick for me:

`pip install msgraph-sdk==1.0.0a14`